# How to call the method after all the celery group tasks are completed in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, celery, celery-task

Currently I am doing the celery group task and I want to call upload_local_directory(output_file)method after all the tasks completed. I tried below approach but its not waiting the job to be completed.

```
tasks = [make_tmp_files.s(page.object_list, path + str(uuid.uuid4() + '.csv')) for page in paginator]
job = group(tasks)
job.apply_async()
job.get()

output_file = 'final.zip'
upload_local_directory_into_S3(output_file)
```

`make_tmp_files` method is the celery job method.

“backend” also defined in the celery object.

please comment If more information needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either [chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) your group and the final, `make_tmp_files` task, or you use [Chord](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords) to accomplish the same. Do not be alarmed if you see that Celery automatically converts group+task chain into a Chord.

Comment: Chord with callback will help that.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Within celery there is a difference between a group of tasks and a group of task results. If you were to change your code to the following it should work:

```
tasks = [make_tmp_files.s(page.object_list, path + str(uuid.uuid4() + '.csv')) for page in paginator]
job = group(tasks)
job_results = job.apply_async()
job_results.get()

output_file = 'final.zip'
upload_local_directory_into_S3(output_file)
```

`job.apply_async()` returns a group of AsyncResults. As a user, you need to check the result of AsyncResult, not the tasks themselves.

Reference: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups

Hopefully that helps!